# get IndexPath in a Sorted Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, plist

I am getting values which are sorted from a plist and displaying them in a `tableview`. I am providing the capability of entering a custom category which will be written to  plist. But I want that to be Inserted in the sorted alphabetical order. Can someone suggest me how to get the `indexpath` of the row where it has to be inserted. I have used the following code where the custom entry will be inserted at the 0 location

```
NSInteger section = 0;
NSInteger row = 0;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

NSDictionary *categoryDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[categoryDictionary setValue:newCategoryName forKey:@"name" ];
[categoryDictionary setValue:@"custom.png" forKey:@"image"];

[[self categoriesArray]insertObject:categoryDictionary atIndex:row];
[[self categoriesArray] writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

NSArray *indexPathsToInsert = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[[self tableView]insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.categoriesArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
NSMutableDictionary *categoryDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[categoryDictionary setObject:newCategoryName forKey:@"name" ];
[categoryDictionary setObject:@"custom.png" forKey:@"image"];

//Add new category to array
[self.categoriesArray addObject:categoryDictionary];

//Sort Array
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[self.categoriesArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

//Write array to plist
[self.categoriesArray  writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

NSInteger section = 0;
//Get the index of saved Category item
NSInteger row = [self.categoriesArray indexOfObject:categoryDictionary];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x8b7e580> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Can you put breakpoint and tell me where you the code is breaking. The self.categoriesArray only has dictionary objects rite, and they all have a key "name", i did the sort assuming these. Please check that as well

Comment: the error is at sortUsingDescriptors line.Yes it is an array of dictionaries and it has a key "name"

Comment: @ChandraSekhar can you provide the log of categoriesArray just before sorting?

Comment: I sorted it out. now it is working but the custom category is getting added at the last row

Comment: @ChandraSekhar What was the issue, my sample code was working good.

Comment: sorry my bad,its working but looks like its case sensitive.I added lowercase a and it added at the end.and i added A and it got added at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

In your table you will get section and row using following

```
NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array of sortable items, you can use this code snippet as help:

```
    NSArray *sortedArray = @[@"a" , @"b", @"d", @"c", @"f"];
    sortedArray = [sortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);

    int c = [sortedArray indexOfObject:@"c"];
    NSLog(@"%d", c);
```

Logs ->

```
(
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    f
)
2
```

so you first insert your object in the "toSort" array and then get the index of it ;)